# MiniFMOD compilation

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, audio, fmod

I'm starting development, and yet having lots of problems coming out from the moment I 'm trying to go a little bit out of bounds.
I usually work with CodeBlocks and just tried once to compile using MinGW.
I'm just starting to do program with the GTK library, my other programs were console applications.
So I've downloaded MiniFMOD 1.70 and 1.60 on http://www.fmod.org/index.php/download.

When I compile the main.cpp on a C++ console application project
I get this message (for both MiniFMOD versions).

> ||=== tryfmod170, Debug ===|
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\Vincent\Bureau\minifmod170\lib\music.h|266|error: redefinition of typedef 'FMUSIC_MODULE'|
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\Vincent\Bureau\minifmod170\lib\minifmod.h|26|note: previous declaration of 'FMUSIC_MODULE' was here|
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\Vincent\Bureau\minifmod170\lib\Fmusic.c|117|error: conflicting types for 'FMUSIC_LoadSong'|
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\Vincent\Bureau\minifmod170\lib\minifmod.h|56|note: previous declaration of 'FMUSIC_LoadSong' was here|
>
> ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|

I'm sure it is a pretty simple error but I assume I'm quickly getting confused between all the file types,variables,structures and platforms...a
If somebody could help me I would be very grateful

Comment: anyone had the same kind of problem???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are including music.h and minifmod.h both of which have typedefs for FMUSIC_MODULE. I think you just need minifmod.h as it is the interface header, music.h is an internal header.